# How to write a query to find Events of a specific Lead or Contact?

Tags: rest-api, rest

Using the REST API (no Apex code), I want to get all the Events of a specific Lead or Contact (I have the Lead Id or the Contact Id) that has a specific string in the Description. What would that query look like?

Also, if you know of a good tutorial on how to form these queries, I'd really appreciate it! All of the examples I've seen are trivial (selecting from 1 record type, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible. The description field (for that matter, any long-text field) cannot be used in the filter or WHERE clause of a SOQL query.  Excluding the filter on Description, here is what your REST call would look like

```
/services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+FROM+Event+WHERE+WhoId+=+'YOUR_LEAD_OR_CONTACT_ID'
```

I recommend using the REST Explorer in Workbench to test your REST callouts: https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Nooooo! I knew something like that would happen.